# Android open URL onclick certain button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How i can send people to my google play on click certain button ?
i already did this in activity_menu.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/ratebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/morebutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/morebutton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/morebutton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/aboutButton"
        android:background="@drawable/more"
        android:text="@string/rateBtn"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textColorHint="@color/White"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

but in MenuActivity.java i couldn't know what should i do ?

Any help?  Thanks

Comment: Google Play app home or to some app?

Comment: Just set OnClickListener for your Button in your activity class.

Comment: @berserk to app page on google play

Comment: See Suhail Mehta's answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
findViewById(R.id.ratebutton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = "market://details?id=<package_name>";

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Button rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rate);
rate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename"));
            startActivity(i2);
            }
        });
```

// Enter package name of application in place of yourpackagename

Answer (score 2):

In my `signin.xml` file I put this code:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/privacypolicylink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="performSingUpMethod"
        android:text="Política de Privacidad"
        android:textColor="#A9A9A9"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In my `signin.java` file I used this:

```
findViewById(R.id.privacypolicylink).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "https://example.net/privacy_policy";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

It works for me. It displays a text in the grey color that I want it. The text is underlined and it is a link. The is the way it looks:

[image]

When I click on it, I see this:

[image]

Then I can open the link using a web browser on the phone and everything works correctly the way I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare button inside your activity:

```
Button btnRateButton;
```

Initialize btnRateButton inside onCreate method:

```
btnRateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ratebutton);
```

Set on click listener:

```
btnRateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Write onclick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = null;
    final String myPackage = getPackageName();
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnRateButton) {
        i = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + myPackage));
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Note that for above code to work, you need to have Play Store app installed on your device.